# Hibernate CompositeUserType for immutable object

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm creating a `CompositeUserType` in hibernate to map `EAST` and `NORTH` fields to a Coordinate object.  At present my Coordinate object is immutable, and I'd like to keep it that way if possible.

I've written my `nullSafeGet`, pulling the coordinates from the ResultSet and calling the constructor:

```
@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
            SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    Integer easting = (Integer)Hibernate.INTEGER.nullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
    Integer northing = (Integer)Hibernate.INTEGER.nullSafeGet(rs, names[1]);
    if(easting==null || northing==null)
        return null;
    return new Coordinate(easting, northing);
}
```

I don't know what to do with `setPropertyValue`, which seems to want to set the coords one at a time.  It is possible to instantiate an immutable object with `CompositeUserType`, or I am trying to do the impossible?

(Also trying to work out what to do about Hibernate.INTEGER being deprecated, but one thing at a time...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`setPropertyValue()` is never called if `isMutable()` returns `false`, so you can throw `UnsupportedOperationException` from it.